# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, exc-bad-access, uiapplicationdelegate

I have loaded data of my apps in UITableView from array declared in AppDelegate. But when I try to scroll the table view I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Following is the code that I have used for configuring the cell.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ScoutAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ScoutAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication     sharedApplication] delegate];
    return appDelegate.playerList.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    ScoutAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ScoutAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Player *tempPlayer = (Player *)[appDelegate.playerList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text= tempPlayer.playerName;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: nothing much in log 
2011-06-21 15:49:33.519 Scout[5799:207] File exist : /Users/ryanfannin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/C78E05BD-8E2B-48E0-8C33-BD8FAEE76905/Documents
2011-06-21 15:49:33.522 Scout[5799:207] Started the Database
2011-06-21 15:49:33.969 Scout[5799:207] Record Count:833

Comment: Once the app crashes, type backtrace and press enter in the console window. This should give you the stack trace at the time of the crash. Also, if you are using Xcode 4, I like to use set the exception breakpoint, it can help in certain cases. http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2011/04/18/xcode-4-exception-breakpoint/

Comment: Try also with NSZombieEnabled. Perhaps you'll get the functions that crashes. ;-)

Comment: My first guess is that your playerList isn't properly retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems to be while I was populating objects for delegate array, I did not used 'self' word before property which resulted in setting pointer to 1st element every time and ultimately crashing my program when I tried to scroll it down. Thanks a lot for all comments.